# Integer partitions of $N$ into three distinct parts

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways are there to partition 10 into 3 distinct parts?

For example, $\{7,2,1 \}$, $\{6,3,1 \}$ and $\{5,4,1\}$ are valid partitions, but $\{4,5,1\}$ would not be an additional partition because it has the same elements as $\{5,4,1\}$. $\{8,1,1\}$ is not admissible because it has two 1's.

Comment: ....What......?

Comment: Thanks @HenningMakholm I think that is exactly what I was looking for.

Edit: Actually nope. I did 10 in a binomial coefficient calculator and it said there was 120 different ways, when there should only be 3 (the above).

Comment: $4$th way: $\{2,3,5\}$.

Answer (score 2):

If $N=6k$ (where $n\in \mathbb{N}$), then there are:

$3k-2$ ways with the smallest part $1$: $(1,2,6k-3), \ldots, (1,3k-1, 3k)$;
$3k-4$ ways with the smallest part $2$: $(2,3,6k-5), \ldots, (2,3k-2, 3k)$;
$3k-5$ ways with the smallest part $3$: $(3,4,6k-7), \ldots, (3,3k-2, 3k-1)$;
$3k-7$ ways with the smallest part $4$: $(4,5,6k-9), \ldots, (4,3k-3, 3k-1)$;
$\cdots$
and $1$ way with the smallest part $4$: $(2k-1,2k,2k+1)$.

So, totally, we have total number of ways (denote it $W$):
$$
W = (3k-2) + (3k-4) + (3k-5) + (3k-7) + ... + 7 + 5 + 4 + 2 + 1 \\ = (6k-6) + (6k-12) + ... + 6 + 1 = \\ 6\Bigl((k-1)+(k-2)+...+2+1\Bigr) + 1 = 3k(k-1)+1 \\ = 3k^2-3k+1.
$$

In similar way, we can get:

if $N=6k+1$, then $W = 3k^2-2k$;
if $N=6k+2$, then $W = 3k^2-k$;
if $N=6k+3$, then $W = 3k^2$;
if $N=6k+4$, then $W = 3k^2+k$;
if $N=6k+5$, then $W = 3k^2+2k$.

---

if $N=10$, then $N=6\cdot 1 + 4$, so $k=1$, and $W=3k^2+k=3+1=4$.

Answer (score 1):

The [Wikipedia article on partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Restricted_part_size_or_number_of_parts) indicates how to see that the number of partitions into at most three parts is the same as the number of partitions with greatest part at most three.  It gives the number of partitions of $n$ into at most three parts as the nearest integer to $\frac {(n+3)^2}{12}$, which for $n=10$ is $14$.  For exactly three parts, we subtract the $5$ partitions into $2$ parts and the $1$ partition into $1$ part, leaving $8$.  They are:
$$1,1,8\\1,2,7\\1,3,6\\1,4,5\\2,2,6\\2,3,5\\2,4,4\\3,3,4$$
Of these, four are into distinct parts.  There is also equality between all partitions into distinct parts and all partitions into odd parts, but I don't know how to equate that to your problem with both distinct parts and a given number.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you're looking for different *$3$-element subsets* of $\{1,2,3,\ldots,N\}$?

The number of such subsets is the [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) $\binom{N}{3} = \frac{N(N-1)(N-2)}6$

Comment: I ran 10,3 in a calculator and it said there was 120 different ways, when it should only be 3 (the 3 above).

Comment: @MarcHoover: Oh, so you're looking for _ways to write $10$ as a sum_ of three distinct positive integers, where the order of the summands do not matter? Indeed that is not binomial coefficients; instead see Ross Millikan's answer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer should be:
$\frac{\binom{n-1}{3-1}-3(\left \lceil \frac{n}{2} \right \rceil-1)}{6}$, if n is not divisible by 3.$$$$ 
$\frac{\binom{n-1}{3-1}-3(\left [ \frac{n}{2} \right ]-2)-1}{6}$, if n is  divisible by 3.$$$$

1) The number of positive integer solutions of equation:
$$x_{1}+x_{2}+...+x_{r}=n$$ is $$\binom{n-1}{r-1}$$.
In this case, it is $$\binom{n-1}{3-1}$$
2) The number of solutions that $x_{i} = x_{j} = x_{k}$ is 1 if n is  divisible by $3$ or $0$ if not. This solution is counted once only if there is.$$$$
3) The number of solutions that $x_{i} = x_{j} \neq  x_{k}$ is $\left \lceil \frac{n}{2} \right \rceil-1$ if n is not divisible by 3.$$$$
The number of solutions that $x_{i} = x_{j} \neq  x_{k}$ is $\left \lceil \frac{n}{2} \right \rceil-2$ if n is divisible by 3. Dont count the case $x_{i} = x_{j} = x_{k}$.$$$$
$\left \lceil  \right \rceil$is the ceiling function. These solutions are count 3 times.$$$$
4) When $x_{i} \neq  x_{j} \neq  x_{k}$. They are count 3! times.$$$$

Exp: $n = 10$: number of solution is $4$.

Answer (score -1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STtFO.png)The formula `<C(n+2,2)/6-0.75*(n+1)+89/72>` is the answer of the number of solutions of a+b+c=n, where a,b,c>0 and `<x>` is the integer closest to x